# System.String to Macaddr

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I have a problem with .NET and PostgreSQL.

I'm trying to save the string, which contains the mac address, to PostgreSQL, but I'm getting the following error:

"Can't write CLR type System.String with handler type MacaddrHandler"

This is the code, which I'm trying to use:

```
NpgsqlBatchCommand command = new NpgsqlBatchCommand("INSERT INTO table (param1,param2,param3) VALUES ($1,$2,$3)")
                {
                    Parameters =
                        {
                            new() {Value = param1},
                            new() {Value = param2, NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.MacAddr8},
                            new() {Value = param3}
                        }
                };
```

Explanation:

param2 represents string, which contains mac address as a string

I tried to change NpgsqlDbType, but unfortunately, it didn't help. I tried also check in official documentation if there is any example how it should be done, but I couldn't find anything

Comment: That `MacaddrHandler` is a clue. That's the type which is mapping between the C# type and the postgres type. [A quick google](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.Internal.TypeHandlers.NetworkHandlers.MacaddrHandler.html), and we see `public class MacaddrHandler : NpgsqlSimpleTypeHandler<PhysicalAddress>`, so it's probably mapping a [`PhysicalAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.physicaladdress?view=net-7.0). Try `new() {Value = PhysicalAddress.Parse(param2), NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.MacAddr8}`

Answer (score 0):

That `MacaddrHandler` is a clue. That's the type which is mapping between the C# type and the postgres type.

[A quick google](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.Internal.TypeHandlers.NetworkHandlers.MacaddrHandler.html), and we see:

```
public class MacaddrHandler : NpgsqlSimpleTypeHandler<PhysicalAddress>
```

So it's probably mapping a [`PhysicalAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.networkinformation.physicaladdress?view=net-7.0).

Try:

```
new() {Value = PhysicalAddress.Parse(param2), NpgsqlDbType = NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.MacAddr8}
```